# How to get the data of a category in my catalog?

Tags: magento-1.8, category

I use these lines to get the data of a **product** in the catalog,

```
// Get product data.
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product_id = Mage::registry('product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product_id);
```

What about if I want to get the data of a **category** in the catalog?

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail();
```

I get this error,

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   ...\default\template\page\html\banner-category.phtml on line 4

I tried with these as well but the same error,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category_id = Mage::registry('category')->getId();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)->getThumbnail();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($_category) { //you are on the category page
    echo $_category->getThumbnail();
}
else {
    //you are not in a category page
}
```

Comment: In my case:  *Fatal error: Call to a member function getThumbnail() on null in...*

Comment: Are you using the same code as above? If $_category is null then how did it get passed the 'if' condition?